# Return all parents of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a filesystem like XML structure, and now I want to get the "filepath" of a . I tried the following XSLT, but it doesn't work. I only get these errors:

> Warning:
>   XSLTProcessor::transformToXml():
>   Templates: in
>   C:\Users\Ludger\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\CloudAmp\devel\php\localAudioFileLocationScanner.php
>   on line 60
>
> Warning:
>   XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): #0
>   name //file  in
>   C:\Users\Ludger\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\CloudAmp\devel\php\localAudioFileLocationScanner.php
>   on line 60
>
> Warning:
>   XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): #1
>   name //file  in
>   C:\Users\Ludger\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\CloudAmp\devel\php\localAudioFileLocationScanner.php on line 60
>
> [...]
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml():
>   xsltApplyXSLTTemplate: A potential
>   infinite template recursion was
>   detected. You can adjust xsltMaxDepth
>   (--maxdepth) in order to raise the
>   maximum number of nested template
>   calls and variables/params (currently
>   set to 3000). in
>   C:\Users\Ludger\DocumentsXA
>   MPP\htdocs\CloudAmp\devel\php\localAudioFileLocationScanner.php
>   on line 60

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/dir">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::dir" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//file">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::dir" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source XML:

```
<root>
  <path val="C:/Users/">
    <file name="a.txt"/>
    <dir name="aaa">
      <file name="b.txt"/>
      <file name="c.txt"/>
    </dir>
    <dir name="bbb">
      <dir name="ccc">
        <file name="d.txt"/>
      </dir>
    </dir>
  </path>
</root>
```

I can't get it working. It would be great if you can help me out.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is shorter (both by the number of templates and number of non-empty lines) than the other current answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're matching any `file` element, then applying templates to its parent `dir`, which is matched by the default template for elements, which applies templates to all of its children, resulting in another match of the same `file` and starting an infinite recursion.

*(Note that your template for `dir` elements never matches anything, because it's looking only for `dir` elements that are a child of the root node, of which you have none.)*

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="dir" mode="path">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::dir" mode="path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following output:

```
a.txt
aaa/b.txt
aaa/c.txt
bbb/ccc/d.txt
```

**Edit:** I think it's generally better to push forward through the document when backtracking can be avoided. The following stylesheet produces the same output as above, but is more efficient and elegant:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="dir">
        <xsl:param name="prev" select="''" />
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="concat($prev, @name, '/')" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:param name="prev" select="''" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($prev, @name)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Correct but starting `//` operator is not needed in patterns nor first `dir` rule (same behavior than built-in rule for any element)

Comment: @Alejandro - The `//` is a relic of copy/paste. Not sure what I was thinking with the `dir` template. I think that's a leftover from an earlier solution that should have been refactored out. As always, thanks for your improvements.

Comment: @lugy2001 - There's nothing really wrong with my previous answer, but I've added another approach that you might find interesting, as well.

Comment: Credit to @Alejandro for inspiring the updated approach, which is based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470269/how-to-create-a-table-of-contents-with-all-levels-of-hierarchy/3470576#3470576

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="file">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildPath"
   select="ancestor::*[not(self::root or self::path)]"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="buildPath">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'/')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <path val="C:/Users/">
        <file name="a.txt"/>
        <dir name="aaa">
            <file name="b.txt"/>
            <file name="c.txt"/>
        </dir>
        <dir name="bbb">
            <dir name="ccc">
                <file name="d.txt"/>
            </dir>
        </dir>
    </path>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
a.txt
aaa/b.txt
aaa/c.txt
bbb/ccc/d.txt
```